# Angular singleton service initialization wait for promise

Tags: angular

I have a service `MyService`:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

and inside its constructor, I access variables that are filled by a method `myMehod()` in `AnotherService` which returns a promise.

How can I tell `MyService` to wait for `myMethod()`?

I want to avoid:

```js
constructor(private anotherService: AnotherService){
   this.anotherService.myMethod().then(() {
      //access variables here
   })
}
```

For module initialization I did something like the following in the `myModule.module.ts` file:

```js
...

{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: myProviderFactory, deps: [AnotherService], multi: true }

...


export function myProviderFactory(provider: AnotherService) {
  return () => provider.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried async - await pattern?

Comment: no since its unclear for me where i would add this to hook into the lifecycle

Comment: What if you directly do `return provider.myMethod();` ?

Comment: where should i return that?